# How to pass string to double from NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c

In array I do have two values value1="234.3423" value2="12.60348" i need to pass this value to varable double x, double y;

How to do this

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you need to turn them into the number (which you're giving in C string syntax here) into an NSString:

```
char *value1 = "234.3423";
NSString *string1 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:value1];
```

Then, simply do this:

```
double x = [string1 doubleValue];
```

That's it. If the simple number parsing of `NSString` is not enough for you, you will need to look into `NSNumberFormatter`.

Comment: double x=[[myArrayList objectAtIndext:1] doubleValue];                            double y=[[myArrayList objectAtIndext:2] doubleValue];                     Do i do like this .

Comment: @kiran kumar: Yes, that's perfectly fine. But note that indexes start with 0. So the first element in the array has index 0, the second 1, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
double x=[[myArrayList objectAtIndext:1] doubleValue]; 
double y=[[myArrayList objectAtIndext:2] doubleValue];
```

Hope its works for me :D

If not help me any another easy way.